# Laptop crashing when running heavy graphics applications

Tags: cpu, crash

My Neo Basic B5700N laptop crashes every time I run a graphics-heavy game and during rendering on a 3D Modeling application called Blender.

My CPU is an Intel Core i7-2630QM and has no graphics card, just the Intel integrated graphics. What is causing the crashing, and how do I solve the crashing problem?

Specifications:
• CPU: Intel Core i7-2630QM, 2.0 GHz, 6 MB Cache
• RAM: 2GB DDR3
• Screen: 14" LCD Display (1366x768)
• Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: Do you know how event viewer works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CPU may be overheating under the increased workload of graphics-intensive applications like Blender. For the time being you should install a CPU temperature monitoring application like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) in your laptop. It may also help to have a computer technician check if the aluminum heat sink on top of the CPU is clogged up with dust and needs cleaning.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a laptop. I'm saving up for a desktop computer but it's gonna take some time. Is there a temporary way of preventing the crash? Reducing the quality of the game through it's settings for example? Is it okay if I ask what causes the crashing?

Comment: Is it possible to install a graphics card to my laptop? It's a Neo Basic B5700N.

Comment: Because a laptop is sold as an integrated unit, if you install your own graphics card in it, you might break the laptop.

Comment: Ok. So it's hopeles for me, huh. Anyways! Thanks for you answer! But I have one last question. That aluminum cooling block, can I buy on a computer store or something. To be honest, I actually disassembled my laptop and brought it back so I know where the cpu is. I'm a super noob but I like doing it all myself since I'm leaving in a city where computer technicians cannot be trusted(based on past experiences). I think I know where to put that cooling block but can I buy it on a computer store?

Comment: If there is dust clogged in the aluminum cooling block, it is very easy to clean it with a spray can of compressed air. Just take the computer outside and spray it, while holding the fan blades so that they don't spin too fast. The only reason that you need the computer technician is that with some laptops it is very difficult to open the case and then close it again except for a computer technician using special tools.

Comment: I recommend using the event viewer like Rudoph suggested. The CPU has throttling that kicks in during thermal overload - so it shouldn't result in a crash. The crash is likely due to a malformed driver somewhere - the event logs would be a good first step to root cause the point of failure.